# Vue3 + Vanta: Create transparent gradient on canvas

Tags: css, vue.js

I have this vue3 app (min. example here on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-vanta-gradient-t6u7s?file=/src/components/Background.vue), when the preview throws an error just click the little refresh button) where [Vanta](https://github.com/tengbao/vanta) is used to create this background animation. What I would like to do is to fade it with a linear gradient. But I cannot get it to work.

I have tried to add a `background-image` property to a `div` that wraps the `v-vanta` component and a `mask-image` css property, directly applied to the element itself. Some googling showed that this won't work on a canvas object that Vanta uses under the hood.

Does anybody have some insight on this?